# Error creating new column from series and list / list and series cleaning advice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with a column of job titles and the company name in the same string of each row **df['Titles']**, I also have a list of all possible company names **joblist**

Im attempting to create a new column **df['Company']** based on a match condition with the list/series but both options are failing due to what I think is a dirty list/series

my list/series is about 3000+ names and I'm wondering whats the best way to clean it, using a general regex or something?

the code for the list, then series was given to me by a stack user and is as follows;

```
df['Company'] = df['Title'].str.contains('|'.join(joblist))

df['Company'] = df['Title'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(joblist)})', expand=False)
```

the errors are as follows;

The list returns: 'error unbalanced parenthesis at position 8466'

The series returns: 'bad escape \C at position 9401'

I have cleaned some basic stuff like "'s" to just "s" nut still get both errors, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some regex characters, so raised error. Solution is escape values by `re.escape`:

```
import re

pat = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in joblist)

df['Company'] = df['Title'].str.contains(pat)

df['Company'] = df['Title'].str.extract(f'({pat})', expand=False)
```